# ASP.NET Dropdown passing null value to controller action

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have html dropdown

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SetCulture", "Home"))
{
    <fieldset>
        <select id="lngSelect" class="form-control">
            <option name="culture" id="en-us" value="en-us">Eng</option>
            <option name="culture" id="es" value="es">Es</option>
            <option name="culture" id="ar" value="ar">Ar</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
}
```

jquery script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $("#lngSelect").change(function () {
            $(this).parents("form").submit(); // post form
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

and controller action

```
public ActionResult SetCulture(string culture)
{
    ...
}
```

I need to pass value selected option to controller, but value passed is null instead of en-us, es, ar... I have tried to change name of controller parameter to "id" and "value", but still it's null in controller..

Can someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` attribute should be on `select` itself and not on `option`:

```
<select name="culture" id="lngSelect" class="form-control">
  <option  id="en-us" value="en-us">Eng</option>
  <option  id="es" value="es">Es</option>
  <option  id="ar" value="ar">Ar</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `<select>` does not have a `name` attribute so there is no name/value pair to submit. Change it to

```
<select id="lngSelect" name="culture" class="form-control">
    ....
</select>
```